# Simultaneous sessions of Rstudio

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio, simultaneous

Is it possible to somehow open several `RStudio`s at the same time? I have `Rstudio` open, and when I try to open another one, nothing happens. What is the proper way to work on several projects simultaneously in `RStudio`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your work is contained in a separate RStudio project file, it should be as simple as selecting "Open Project in New Session", either from the File menu or from the project selector in the upper-right (at least on a Mac).

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows machine you can "scroll click" on the icon and it will open a new session. You could probably also right click and choose something, not on a PC right now so cant tell for sure.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. What is scroll click? And if I right click, then what to do? thanks

Comment: One my mouse I have a scroll which I can click, using that on the R icon opens a new session for me.

Comment: How to do it in Linux Operating Systems?